# Oscillating along a circle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator

Suppose there is a round track which a particle will be traversing (a.k.a vertical circular motion of ideal string). Now we know that if the circle is divided into four quarter circles, there is no possibility of the particle being detached whereas at the top most point or second quarter of the circle, the possibility of the particle being detached is pretty high. I have been told that if the velocity of the particle at any point becomes $0$, then the particle will move to and fro along the circular arc. But velocity $0$ means tension is also $0$ (at the end point of the first quarter). So it should have done a projectile motion, isn't it? Why does it then move to and fro?

Comment: I think whoever said that to you didn't mean a particle in a circular motion tied to a string but more of like a circular track that is a tube, like imagine a ball in a donut shaped track.

Answer (score 1):

If the particle achieves zero velocity before entering the upper quarters,  then it will indeed undergo oscillatory motion.

In the case where the particle just reaches the horizontal extreme, the tension, as you pointed out is zero, so the only non zero force acting on the particle is the gravitational pull of earth, so in the small time interval $dt$ , it moves under the influence of gravity with its accleration pointing downwards,  but in this small time, it gains some velocity $dv$. But due to the presence of the string,  as the particle cannot fall in a straight line. Therefore almost immediately Tension again becomes non zero to constrict the path of the parricle and it retraces the path it took to reach the horizontal maximum from the vertical minimum (bottom-most point).

If on the other hand,  the particle attains zero velocity after entering the upper quarters,  things become different, now the particle will continue to fall for some time in a straight line because of slacking of the string,  as soon as the string becomes straight, impulsive tension will act on it, and the particle would oscillate along the same path within the bottom quarters.